# Quartiles for Calculations

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am working to recreate a capabilities analysis in Power BI visualizations.  As there are no real stats capabilities I am having to create from scratch.  I am running into a little issue when I try to get the average of my 3rd quartile for a "BSTP" Best Short Term Performance measurement.  The formula for calculating BSTP is

Goal = Baseline (µ) + |0.7 x (BSTP - Baseline (µ))|

(µ) is the AVERAGE()  that is easy check
0.7 = variance of the process again easy and check

BSTP = 3rd Quartile average / count of data points in 3rd Quartile  not so easy and no check...

For calculation example...

Lest say we have 100 data points equally distributed from 0 - 100

- Min = 1
- Q1 = 25
- Q2 = 50
- Q3 = 75
- Q4 = 100

This process BSTP calculation from excel would be as follows

SUMIF("data value" >= 75 (Q3)/ COUNTIF("data value" >= 75)

So if the "data value" is greaterthan or equal to 75 sum then divide by the count of data that are greaterthan or equal to 75... In this example we would have 25 data values between 51-75 that equal 1575, 51+52+53+54....  There were 25 data points summed up so the final calculation would be

1575/25 = 63 (BSTP)

to sum up...  This is the formula I am trying to solve for in power bi

```
SUMIF("data value" >= 75 (Q3)/ COUNTIF("data value" >= 75)
```

I appreciate your insights!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DAX does have some stats functions, so this one is pretty simple.

If you're looking for the average of the 3rd quartile, then you want

```
SUMIF( 50 <= "data value" < 75 ) / COUNTIF( 50 <= "data value" < 75 )
```

or simply

```
AVERAGEIF( 50 <= "data value" < 75 )
```

---

You can use the percentile functions calculate where your quartiles lie an then average over that subset:

```
3rdQtlAvg =
VAR Q2 = PERCENTILE.INC ( Table1[Val], 0.50 )
VAR Q3 = PERCENTILE.EXC ( Table1[Val], 0.75 )
RETURN
    AVERAGEX (
        FILTER ( Table1,
            Table1[Val] >= Q2 &&
            Table1[Val] <= Q3 ),
        Table1[Val]
    )
```